# Gensim sort_by_descending_frequency changes most_similar results

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, fasttext

It seems that when retrieving the most similar word vectors, sorting by word frequency will change the results in `Gensim`.

Before sorting:

```
from gensim.models import FastText
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts  # some example sentences
print(len(common_texts))
model = FastText(vector_size=4, window=3, min_count=1)  # instantiate
model.build_vocab(corpus_iterable=common_texts)
model.train(corpus_iterable=common_texts, total_examples=len(common_texts), epochs=1)  

model.wv.most_similar(positive=["human"])
```

> ```
> [('interface', 0.7432922720909119),
>  ('minors', 0.6719315052032471),
>  ('time', 0.3513716757297516),
>  ('computer', 0.05815044790506363),
>  ('response', -0.11714297533035278),
>  ('graph', -0.15643596649169922),
>  ('eps', -0.2679084539413452),
>  ('survey', -0.34035828709602356),
>  ('trees', -0.63677978515625),
>  ('user', -0.6500451564788818)]
> ```

However, if I sort the vectors by descending frequency:

```
model.wv.sort_by_descending_frequency()

model.wv.most_similar(positive=["human"])
```

> ```
> [('minors', 0.9638221263885498),
>  ('time', 0.6335864067077637),
>  ('interface', 0.40014874935150146),
>  ('computer', 0.03224882856011391),
>  ('response', -0.14850640296936035),
>  ('graph', -0.2249641716480255),
>  ('survey', -0.26847705245018005),
>  ('user', -0.45202943682670593),
>  ('eps', -0.497650682926178),
>  ('trees', -0.6367797255516052)]
> ```

The most similar word ranking as well as the word similarities change. Any idea why?

**Update:**

Before calling sort:

```
model.wv.index_to_key
```

> ```
> ['system',
>  'graph',
>  'trees',
>  'user',
>  'minors',
>  'eps',
>  'time',
>  'response',
>  'survey',
>  'computer',
>  'interface',
>  'human']
> ```

```
model.wv.expandos['count']
```

> array([4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])

After calling sort:

```
model.wv.index_to_key
```

> ```
> ['system',
>  'user',
>  'trees',
>  'graph',
>  'human',
>  'interface',
>  'computer',
>  'survey',
>  'response',
>  'time',
>  'eps',
>  'minors']
> ```

```
model.wv.expandos['count']
```

> array([4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That change-of-reported similarities definitely **shouldn't** happen, so something is surely going wrong here. (Maybe, cached-subword info isn't re-sorting.)

But also note:

- That method wasn't particularly meant for use *after* training - indeed, you should be seeing a warning message if using it that way.
- Such a sort *should already happen by default* in all 2Vec algorithms at the end of vocab-discovery phase - it's the usual behavior, only rarely turned off. So requesting it again should at most be a no-op.

To dig into what may be gowing wrong, can you edit your question to show the values of both…

- `model.wv.index_to_key`
- `model.wv.expandos['count']`

…before *and* after the `. sort_by_descending_frequency()` call?

Comment: Thanks @gojomo. I have updated my question.

Comment: Thanks! The update indicates the re-sort isn't 'stable' - words that were tied, and in a certain order, might be in a different order after the re-sort. That may be part of the problem for you, but the change of the sim values for word pairs is definitely some other bug, as well. Still, the workaround for now is: don't make this unnecessary call. Your words are already frequency-sorted. I'll also add some comments on the associated Github bug: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/3196